# Oracle : Deadlock occurs but no details in logs can be found in trace

Tags: oracle, logging, deadlock

I'm having a reccurent deadlock on one of my PL/SQL stored procedure.
It happens 1 out of 50 times i'd say.
Always on the same line.

I have check the most common causes like having index on my foreign keys.

I know it's encountering deadlock since this PL/SQL Procedure insert the DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK in a custom log table.

Below is what my custom log table is reporting

```
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
ORA-06512: at "USER.PROC_NAME", line 554
```

Apparently I should be able to get more details like a Deadlock Graph to help me find the cause in the oracle logs.

I runned the following to find out where the errors are logged ( select * from V$DIAG_INFO;)

It returned me the following

```
Diag Trace  E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\bdes\bdes\trace
Diag Alert  E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\bdes\bdes\alert
```

I went to those folders and couldn't find anything around the deadlock time in the alert folder.
In the trace folder I find something 6 seconds earlier my custom log with the following

```
Trace file E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\bdes\bdes\trace\bdes_ora_1476.trc
    Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
    Build label:    RDBMS_12.2.0.1.0_WINDOWS.X64_170210.4
    Windows NT Version V6.2  
    ORACLE_HOME =  E:\oracle\product\12.2.0
    Node name           : *****
    CPU                 : 8 - type 8664, 8 Physical Cores
    Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000
    Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:14827M/32767M, Ph+PgF:19325M/37631M 
    VM name             : VMWare Version (6)
    Instance name: *****
    Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
    Oracle process number: 23
    Windows thread id: 1476, image: ORACLE.EXE (SHAD)


    *** 2018-08-03T10:04:21.754777+02:00
```

Below that there is nothing and I feel like i should have something like the question in this thread
[How can I identify the rows involved in an Oracle deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577000/how-can-i-identify-the-rows-involved-in-an-oracle-deadlock)

Am I supposed to enable something ? What am I missing ?

Thank you for your time and let me know if I can give you more helpfull infos.

Comment: The main database alert log (the one that records startups, shutdowns, checkpoints, logfile switches, etc) will have an entry written when the deadlock happens.  That entry will indicate the name of the detailed trace file was was generated for the incident.  This belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Unfortunatly no log file has been updated after this error when i checked so i'm 100% sure it didn't log where I was looking.

I have two theories.
Could it be possible that it doesn't log since i'm catching the deadlock in the plsql exception block ?
Or I'm simply not looking at the right place but I doubt that..

Comment: What I was trying to say is you don't have to guess about where to look.  The database alert log will record the incident and tell you the name and location of the trace file it generated.

Comment: I may have missed the main folder then because I dont see thoses logs.
Since no one seems to say that I have to enable something I'm probably looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Run this query and then see if you can find the file have the path and file name specified on your database server.  `select di.value path, 'alert_' || i.instance_name || '.log' from v$diag_info di, v$instance i where di.name = 'Diag Trace'`

Comment: Thank you, I checked the file returned by this command and realised that it says there is not enough space anymore to write logs.
I guess that's probably related to my issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around, I checked the directory returned by this query `select di.value path, 'alert_' || i.instance_name || '.log' from v$diag_info di, v$instance i where di.name = 'Diag Trace'` and the issue was due to a lack of space on disk...

Thank you for the help

( query by @matthew-mcpeak )

Answer (score 0):

Could you post line `554` and surrounding from `USER.PROC_NAME`? It should be enough to analyse source code of procedure to know what is the problem. From my experience, deadlocks are quite often the result of doing things automagically using triggers...

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but I'm not really looking for a fix here.

This deadlock happens not often and has no consequences. 
I'm trying to understand why I can't find those alerts logs when my exception handler tells me a deadlock happened..